# Cannot add API properly in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api

I am trying to add an external api to my java project in eclipse. 
After downloading the api folder from sourceforge, i find the following files:
jeplite-0.8.7.jar
jeplite-0.8.7a-bin.jar
jeplite-0.8.7a-src.jar

this is what ive been doing:
1)copy jeplite-0.8.7.jar into a libs folder in my project
2)Right click project, go to properties
3)Select Java Build Path from the left pane and then click on the Libraries tab
4)Click on Add Jars and navigate to jeplite-0.8.7.jar
5)Click ok and jeplite-0.8.7.jar shows up in the Referenced Libraries folder

However, this does not work. I cannot use the API. I can import the packages but they show up as empty(white package) in the workspace.

Ive tried attaching jeplite-0.8.7a-src.jar as a source but that doesn't work.
This is the api btw: http://jeplite.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file with a zip tool, and you'll discover it only contains .java source files, and not .class files. You need to add the jeplite-0.8.7a-bin.jar file as a library.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Cant believe i wasted over 2 hours on this. I went back to the text editor and tried manually adding classpaths to see where i was going wrong before i posted this question lol..